# "These" or "Such"

Tags: word-choice, reference

I have an exercise requiring us to complete a text with suitable reference words. Here is a small part of the text:

> A further problem is the availability of software. Educational computer programs can be bought but **these** / **such** programs may not suit the needs of individual classes. Teachers can adapt **such** software to suit their needs in the classroom, but this is time-consuming and often complicated.

In the first blank, we can fill either **these** or **such**, but in the second one, there is only an acceptable answer which is **such**. Why can't we fill **these** in the second blank?

Comment: You can't use ***these*** in the second case because ***software*** is singular (you'd have to say teachers can adopt ***this** software*, or ***these** programs*). But note that saying ***this*** or ***these*** doesn't quite mean the same as ***such*** (the latter includes things ***similar to** what has been mentioned*, whereas the former *specifically and only* references whatever was previously mentioned).

Comment: Note that (through the influence of non-native Anglophones discussing computer technology in English, I suspect), you will occasionally come across people using ***software*** as a plural. But it's not a mainstream usage yet, and possibly never will be.

Comment: Why is **such** the only acceptable answer for the second blank? Why can't we use **this**?

Comment: Like I said in the first comment, you can use ***this software*** or ***these programs***, but you can't really use ***these software*** because ***software*** is normally considered to be singular.

Answer (score 1):

> A further problem is the availability of software. Educational computer programs can be bought but **these** / **such** programs may not suit the needs of individual classes. Teachers can adapt **such** software to suit their needs in the classroom, but this is time-consuming and often complicated.

Concerning your exercise, the first case should be "**these**" in order to refer to the earlier mentioned "*educational computer programs*". The word "**such**" in this case can also be used and won't be incorrect either, however, it would mean "**programs of the kind**" and not particularly "**these programs**". Notice the difference:

- I have rare books and these books cost a lot on the market.
- I have rare books and such books cost a lot on the market.

With "**these**" we only refer to the books I have whereas with "**such**" we refer to any "*rare book*" (book of the kind) and it so happens that mine are of this very kind.

In the second case we can only use "**such**", since with the word "**software**" which is commonly singular, we can't use "**these**", only "**this**". "**such**" here means "*similar software*" or most probably "*software of the kind*" and conveys the kind of software that "**educational computer programs*" imply.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm starting an answer part way into a discussion. The comments to the questionpretty much answer it already. I'll give a summary for completeness, but credit goes to FumbleFingers:

- You can't use these in the second case because software is singular.
- 'such' includes things similar to what has been mentioned.
- 'this' or 'these' specifically and only references whatever was previously mentioned.

In answer to the follow on question:

> Why is such the only acceptable answer for the second blank? Why can't we use this?

"this" vs "such" hinges on specificity. When you say "this software" you are talking about a specific piece or group of software. It's the same as the definite vs indefinite article argument. The prior sentence's "...may not be..." stresses the indefiniteness of the context; thus ruling out the use of a definite "this". The opposite is true for the first 'these/such' where 'Educational computer programs' gives a definite context.

Comment: The comments that "answer" the question are likely to be deleted once someone writes a complete answer that the community can vote on, so you should probably make sure that your answer stands on its own. This [discussion on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/709/) has more details about answering in comments. Also, for when you get the reputation to comment everywhere, there are some [dos and don'ts for commenting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) in the [help].